# JMeter CSV Data for filename

Tags: jmeter

With JMeter files can be sent successfully

Config:
[image]

Output (success):
[image]

But it doesn't work if changing the file name to a variable. 
Attended images you will find file path is set to ${logname}, which can be resolved correctly, but the content-length is incorrect.

After changing the file name to the variable, the http will response  error message, saying "java.io.FileNotFoundException: ulog_5b9139cf-5542-42dc-ae76-7fde3a61c67b_235152af-feb7-4249-a168-12ed4abb426c_0.log (The system cannot find the file specified)".

I think the incorrect content-length led to server fail to read the file content. Is is right? How to fix it? Thanks.

Config:
[image]
Output (failure):
The filename is resolved correctly, but content length is incorrect:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter is looking for the file in it's Base Dir.

If you look into your *jmeter.log* file you'll see something like:

```
2014/03/05 15:52:37 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Default base='/home/jmeter' 
2014/03/05 15:52:37 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='/home/jmeter'
```

This is where JMeter expects file to be located.

So you can either prefix your `${logname}` variable with **full path** to your user's Desktop like

```
C:\Users\youruser\Desktop\${logname}
```

Or alternatively change location where JMeter is looking for files via [Beahshell Pre Processor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) as follows:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;
FileServer.getFileServer().setBaseDir("C:/Users/youruser/Desktop");
```

But use it with caution as it may have impact on other relative paths.